# Question about cronjobs/bash scripts which are not executed

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, cron

I have two scripts which are called via crontab. The first script backs up my database and sends it over to S3. This works seamlessly.

I have a second script which cleans up old backups. The issue is, that this script is not executed properly when it's called via crontab. When I copy the comamnd and execute it myself via the terminal, everything works fine.

Syslog does say this:

```
Feb 20 14:55:01 fp-mysql-slave CRON[357]: (fp) CMD (bash /home/fp/cleanupscript.sh "fp-backups" "10 days")
Feb 20 14:55:01 fp-mysql-slave CRON[356]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

crontab says this:

```
10 */24 * * * bash /home/fp/cleanupscript.sh "fp-backups" "10 days"
```

And when I execute it myself I do see this, so the script is working.

```
s3://fp-backups/db-fp-191221-10_45_01.tar.gz
delete: 's3://fp-backups/db-fp-191221-10_45_01.tar.gz'
```

The file permissions are the same as the other script:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 fp fp  2104 Oct 30  2018 backupscript.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 fp fp   457 Oct  2  2018 cleanupscript.sh
```

Does anybody has an idea what's wrong here?

Comment: The first thing I would do is add something like `>/home/fp/cron.log 2>&1` to the crontab entry so that you can see any error messages that are currently being discarded

Comment: Since it works for you, but not for cron, then start looking at environment variables (`printenv`). Cron operates in a different environment than you do. Missing gull paths to all executables is a common hiccup.

Comment: @user535733 I do not use Gulp or something like this, the script just looks like this:

https://pastebin.com/egsQZpbc

Comment: @steeldriver I did this, and I see this: /home/fp/cleanupscript.sh: line 5: s3cmd: command not found

So fixing the path, this should be it. Thanks!